# Pattern matching on generic type

Tags: scala

I need to know if the generic type is a String in order to perform a different logic on it, like:

```
def compute[A](field: String, record: GenericRecord): A match {
   case String => record.get(field).asInstanceOf[Utf8].toString
   case _ => record.get(field).asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

But I don't know how to get the type of the generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ClassTag` to do matching if you don't need to handle nested types, and `TypeTag` if you need to do it:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

def compute[A: ClassTag](field: String, record: GenericRecord): A = {
  if (classTag[A] == classTag[String]) {
    record.get(field).asInstanceOf[Utf8].toString.asInstanceOf[A]
  } else {
    record.get(field).asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}
```

For `TypeTag`s, import `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeTag}` instead, and change `ClassTag` to `TypeTag` and `classTag` to `typeTag`.

Comment: It won't compile as `.toString` is incompatible with `A`. You probably need to use `.toString.asInstanceOf[A]`.

Comment: @VictorMoroz you're right, of course! Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (probably could be optimized):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def m[A](x: Any)(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]): A = {
  tag.toString match {
    case "java.lang.String" =>
      (x.toString + " is a string").asInstanceOf[A]
    case _ =>
      x.asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}

println(m[String]("123")) // 123 is a string
println(m[Int](456)) // 456
```

Comment: Would use `classOf[String] isAssignableFrom tag.runtimeClass` (rather than `.toString ` based comparison), and use `tag.unapply(x)` (returning safe `Option[A]`, rather than `asInstanceOf`), to benefit from `ClassTag` (and restrict unsafe reflect to its resolution).

Comment: @cchantep `.toString` was a knee jerk reaction, Vladimir Matveev's suggestion  `tag == classTag[String]` is definitely better.